# Powershell 2.0 Enter-PSSession cannot get New-PSDrive working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a remote computer which I can `Enter-PSSession` successfully. When I execute:

```
New-PSDrive -Name "G" -PSProvider Filesystem -Root '\\fileserver\apps\etc'
```

I get the following error:

```
New-PSDrive : Drive root "\\fileserver\apps\etc" does not exist or it's not a folder.
+ CategoryInfo          : ReadError: (G:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DriveRootError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

Now, the location does exist because its mounted on my local computer and remote computer too. Before trying to mount the network drive through Powershell, I typed `Get-PSDrive` to see if it was mounted before - nothing just the normal.

Is there a way to mount a network drive when you are in PSSession?

Answer (score 0):

You have to realize why it fails first. This is second hop issue that causes it.

Several way to fix it:

- net use on remote box (will prompt for password)
- enabling kerberos delegation or constrained kerberos delegation
- enabling CredSSP

This [session](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSDOIxFc2fY) by [Aleksandr Nikolic](https://twitter.com/alexandair) explains it in more detail.

Comment: I will take a look at this and get back with you. Thank you for posting this.